# (~) Why are my bits not flipping?

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

I thought that ~ should make 1s into 0s and vice-versa. I used it in my code, yet I'm getting -2s and -1s.

```
def inverse_graph(graph):
    # for each vertex in graph
    revg = list(graph)
    for i, line in enumerate(revg):
        for j, vertex in enumerate(line):
            if  i != j:
                # flip value
                graph[i][j] = ~ graph[i][j]
                #if vertex == 0:
                #    graph[i][j] = 1;
                #else:
                #    graph[i][j] = 0;
    return revg



def test():
        g1 = [[0, 1, 1, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 1, 1, 0]]
        assert inverse_graph(g1) == [[0, 0, 0, 1],
                                     [0, 0, 1, 0],
                                     [0, 1, 0, 0],
                                     [1, 0, 0, 0]]
        g2 = [[0, 1, 1, 1],
              [1, 0, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 0, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 0]]
        assert inverse_graph(g2) == [[0, 0, 0, 0],
                                     [0, 0, 0, 0],
                                     [0, 0, 0, 0],
                                     [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

.............................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: *I thought that ~ should make 1s into 0s and vice-versa* What result would you expect for the expression `~2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, -2 *is* ~1.  [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement), remember?

```
>>> bin(1)
'0b1'
>>> bin(~1)
'-0b10'
```

The thing is: you're not using bits, but integers.  So either you want to revert to using e.g. Booleans (which read less nicely) or you want to use some expression like `0 if x else 1` to flip your elements.

Tip:  you can use comprehensions to write this more elegantly:

```
>>> flipped = lambda graph: [ [0 if x else 1  for x in row]  for row in graph]
>>> flipped( [ [1, 0], [0, 1] ] )
[[0, 1], [1, 0]]
```

Comment: I think you have mixed `n` and `x` in your inner list comprehension. You need either `if n` or `for x in row` for it to work.

Comment: @Blckknght: and the worst thing is: I tried it out, noticed the same thing, and forgot to update the post.... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With `numpy` it is much easier.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> g1=np.array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
...              [1, 0, 0, 1],
...              [1, 0, 0, 1],
...              [0, 1, 1, 0]])
>>> g2=1-g1
>>> g2
array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

~ will work with Boolean datatype:

```
>>> g1=np.array([[0, 1, 1, 0],   # 1 represents True and 0 represents False
...              [1, 0, 0, 1],
...              [1, 0, 0, 1],
...              [0, 1, 1, 0]], dtype=bool)
>>> ~g1
array([[ True, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

If you want `complement(~)` in 0s and 1s rather than in True False, this will do the trick:

```
>>> ~g1+0
array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Ah... the power of `numpy.array`!

Answer (score 2):

As xtofl has pointed out, Python's integers use Two's complement representation. This means that the bitwise inverse of `0` is not `1`, but an infinitely long sequence of binary `1`s, which is interpreted as `-1`. The inverse of `1` is not `0`, but an infinite number of ones, followed by one zero (which is `-2`).

Of course, the number of bits stored for each integer is not infinite. Python will normally use the C integer type `long` that your system defines (it is usually 32 or maybe 64 bits long), but operations that would overflow will instead automatically switch to Python's own arbitrary precision `long` type if the value is too large to fit (this conversion is handled transparently within the `int` type in Python 3).

Anyway, an alternative solution is to use:

```
graph[i][j] = 1 - graph[i][j]
```

Or, if you don't mind the values becoming instances of the `int` subtype `bool`:

```
graph[i][j] = not graph[i][j]
```

Python's `bool` values are still usable as numbers (`False` works just like `0` and `True` is just like `1`). The only real difference is that they'll print out with text instead of digits.

Comment: Good info and nice alternative approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While the others are right, an easier way of saying `0 if x else 1` is `not x` or maybe `int(not x)`.

`not x` returns `False` if `x != 0` and `True` otherwise. `False` and `True` are `bool`s, which is a subclass of `int`. They can readily be used in a calculation, but for the case you prefer to get proper `0`s and `1`s, or if you need them for indexing a `dict`, `int(not x)` might be better.

Comment: `!` is not an operator in Python, like it is in other languages. The Boolean operator `not` needs to be spelled out.

Comment: @Blckknght Shame on me. I tend to forget about Python :-/ I corrected my answer.